# Align Navbar Links to the Right in fullPage.js

Tags: jquery, css, fullpage.js

I am trying to have my navbar at the bottom and the links aligned to the right side of the viewport. I managed to get the navbar at the bottom, but my links are stuck to the left no matter what I tried.

This is my HTML code:

```
<body>
  <nav class="nav" id="myMenu">
    <a data-menuanchor="sec1"  class="nav-link"  href="#sec1">Section 1</a>
    <a data-menuanchor="sec2" class="nav-link"  href="#sec2">Section 2</a>
  </nav>
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="secc1" >Section 1</div>
    <div class="section" id="secc2" >
      <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="slide"> Slide 2 </div>
      <div class="slide"> Slide 3 </div>
      <div class="slide"> Slide 4 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is my JQuery code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      menu:'#myMenu',
      anchors: ['sec1', 'sec2'],
      sectionsColor: ['#fc6c7c', '#69a366'],
      scrollingSpeed: 1000,
      fixedElements: "#myMenu",

    });

  });
</script>
```

And lastly, the CSS code:

```
<style>
  #myMenu{
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0px; 
    position:absolute;

  }

  .section{
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav-link{
    color:white;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;

  }

  .nav-link:hover{
    color:red;

  }

</style>
```

And, as a side question- I'd love if someone could explain what `menu:` function and 
 `data-menuanchor=` attribute both do since it seems that neither of them makes any difference.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.nav-link {
  color:white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vishal Bhavsar. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: Okay. try text-align: right; in above css for nav-link

Comment: I just found out what the problem was:It has to do with Bootstrap's `nav` class. it should be `<nav class="nav justify-content-end" id="myMenu">` thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use these styles and make sure to add them **after** fullpage.js stylesheet:

```
.fp-slidesNav{
    left: auto !important;
    right: 20px; /* or any other margin you want to the right */
}
```

[Demo online](https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/rz4f2pv8/2/)

Comment: Thanks Alvaro! I asked about nav links items, but since you brought those styles up, I tried to look them up on the GitHub page and somehow could not find them. Is there a list of the all existing available classes (like `.fp-xyz`)

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. That's the class used by fullPage.js for the navigation bullets. That's why you have to use it, to overwrite their default values. 
You can which classes or id they use by inspecting the DOM with Chrome inspector, Safari or Firefox.

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, "That's the class used by fullPage.js" -- my question refers to this quote. Is there any list of all the other classes that exist in fullPage.js? Thanks!